# How to set a range for list values being passed?

Tags: python, list

what I am trying to do is set a range for the x and y coordinates but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried using a for loop but that doesn't also work. I want to set a range for my coordinates and not return the coordinates 50 times.

```
def generate_map(x_range, y_range, locations):  
  x_range = range(-50,50) # how to set a range for this coordinate
  y_range = range(-50,50) # how to set a range for this coordinate

  generated_map = []
  for x in range(locations):
    generated_map.append([x_range,y_range]) #adds x and y coordinates to the list
  return generated_map


number = generate_map(-55,2, 4) #x-coordinate, y-coordinate and how many coordinates you want
print(number)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output? It is not clear to me what `generate_map` should do.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfectly clear to me what you're trying to do here.  If you're trying to create a randomized set of map coordinates within some predefined range then this might improve your chances:

```
import random
def generate_map(x_range, y_range, locations):
   generated_map = []
   for x in range(locations):
     x_range_int = random.randint(-x_range,x_range)
     y_range_int = random.randint(-y_range,y_range)
     generated_map.append([x_range_int,y_range_int]) #adds x and y coordinates to the list
   return generated_map


number = generate_map(55,2, 4)
```